# Python3.8 generic thread error "Exception ignored in thread started by..."

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.8

The program below needs to `import os` to work correctly.

```
from threading import Thread
# import os

class Downloader(Thread):
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
            
    @classmethod
    def run(self):
        os.path.join("aas", "sadas")

def main():
    Downloader().start()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In `python 3.8`, the above program prints a generic error message for any unhandled error occurred in the thread. Same is true for `python 3.9` as well.

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <bound method Thread._bootstrap of <Downloader(Thread-1, started 123145545740288)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 934, in _bootstrap_inner
    self._invoke_excepthook(self)
TypeError: invoke_excepthook() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

While in `python 3.6`, it prints the actual error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "threads.py", line 10, in run
    os.path.join("aas", "sadas")
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

I am having a hard time debugging my threads. The best I can do is to guess the line number and the error. The other posts with the same error deal specifically with the error causing the issue - so not useful.

Why this change in `python 3.8`? Is there any way to display a proper error message?

Comment: Why did you make your methods `classmethod`s?

Comment: It was giving `AssertionError: group argument must be None for now`. Converting to `classmethod` solved the problem. Since I am going to have only one instance of the `Downloader`, it was a good temporary fix. I didn't realize `Thread.__init__(self)` then. Now, it's showing messages as expected. 
But I am still struggling with the concept, and the use of `Thread.__init__` and `super().__init__`.

Comment: I'd stick with ```Thread.__init__()```. This is how the documentation does it.